# Tweet without auto adding url

Tags: php, twitter

I have the following code:

```
<a href="http://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-text="Text text text" data-count="none">
  Tweet
</a>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script>
```

It adds to the text shortened url to the page on which the button was clicked. How can I disable auto adding url? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The point of the twitter share button is to share the site you are on.

You can override it with the data-url attribute.

```
<a href="http://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-url="h" data-count="vertical">Tweet</a><script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script>
```

Comment: See my edits.  The trick is to put a 404ing URL in the data-url attribute (in this case, "h").  If you want to track the number of tweets, be sure to set it to a random string for each page.

Answer (score 0):

You can at a custom url with the data-url attribute, than it ignores the url on the page he currently is:

```
<a href="http://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-url="http://domain.com" data-count="vertical">Tweet</a><script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script>
```